# Why did Google stop showing our reviews rich snippets data?

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets

We have been using rich snippets on our site for a few years now but they stopped working a while ago. The rich snippets do appear if we add site directive to the search.

We have been trying several different way of tagging our data but so far none of them seem to work on SERP without site directive. Below is what we are currently trying. They all validate in the tool, but none of them show up unless we add the site directive to the search...

**Product w Aggregate Rating w Rating Count**

Structured Data Testing Tool: http://bit.ly/1H4UM9r
Google Search: https://www.google.com/search?q=Essence+Silky+Touch+Blush+%28All+Shades%29+reviews&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
Google Search with site directive:
https://www.google.com/search?q=Essence+Silky+Touch+Blush+%28All+Shades%29+reviews&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=Essence+Silky+Touch+Blush+%28All+Shades%29+reviews+site:makeupalley.com

**Aggregate Rating with RatingCount**

Structured Data Testing Tool: http://bit.ly/1Nwvhmg
Google Search: https://www.google.com/search?q=BeneFit+Cosmetics+Rockateur+reviews&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
Google Search with site directive: https://www.google.com/search?q=BeneFit+Cosmetics+Rockateur+reviews&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=BeneFit+Cosmetics+Rockateur+reviews+site:makeupalley.com

**Aggregate Rating with ReviewCount**

Structured Data Testing Tool: http://bit.ly/1S6H0tt
Google Search: https://www.google.com/search?q=NARS+Contour+Blush+reviews%2C+photo&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=NARS+Contour+Blush+reviews
Google Search with site directive: https://www.google.com/search?q=NARS+Contour+Blush+reviews%2C+photo&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=NARS+Contour+Blush+reviews+site:makeupalley.com

**Aggregate Rating with ReviewCuunt and RatingCount**

(Tried this thanks to a suggestion from Grace on this group.. :) )
Structured Data Testing Tool: http://bit.ly/1RxKtAk
Google Search: https://www.google.com/search?q=Lancome+Blush+Subtil+Palette+323+Rose+Flush+reviews&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
Google Search with site directive: https://www.google.com/search?q=Lancome+Blush+Subtil+Palette+323+Rose+Flush+reviews%2C+photos&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=Lancome+Blush+Subtil+Palette+323+Rose+Flush+reviews%2C+photos+site:makeupalley.com

**RDF aggreagate rating**

Structured Data Testing Tool: http://bit.ly/1R9x9SR
Google Search: https://www.google.com/search?q=TheBalm+Frat+Boy+reviews%2C+photos&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
Google Search with site directive: https://www.google.com/search?q=TheBalm+Frat+Boy+reviews%2C+photos&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=TheBalm+Frat+Boy+reviews+site:makeupalley.com

**Rating with author**

Structured Data Testing Tool: http://bit.ly/1NwwaLv
Google Search: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=Manic+Panic+High+Voltage+Semi-Permanent+Hair+Colour+Cream+reviews+&gws_rd=ssl

If anyone can shed a light on how to resolve this issue, we would be very appreciate.

Comment: Google does not guarantee they will show rich snippets. Sorry. I do see them showing up on other SERP listings for your site, however. Perhaps it is just temporary.

Comment: Did you succeed to get your rich snippet starts back?

Comment: Google will have to trust every single websites for self generated reviews. It might be that for a website that has high traffic and a high percentage of conversion, a site that signals google that is useful for people, maybe then google might decide to show the rich snippet reviews (aggregated reviews) on SERP. It is also happening to us so we thought that maybe we are not using the correct structured data or we should switch to json-ld format..in either case, after trying several combinations we saw that regardless google will index the rich snippets (in Google search console) and not displa

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the results that do show ratings, they tend to use third party reviews (the ones I checked were using Bazaarvoice and Power Reviews).

However, as far as I can tell, your site appears to run its own reviews, which Google would then have to trust on you word that they are accurate.

I know the shopping listings require you to use their "[Approved third party product review aggregators](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6059553?hl=en)".  I guess these are seen as more authoritative in general.  Annoyingly, you also have to pay to use most (probably all) of these.

According to [this article](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-rich-snippet-reduction-17579.html), Google have cut back on rich snippets in the past.  They seem so easy to spam, that I'm surprised they ever let them be so open in the first place.

If they appear when you add your site directive to the search term, that to me proves you are still marked up correctly and you have no on-site coding issues.

It seems another case of "only Google will really know why", but it would certainly seem sensible to me that untrusted reviews only appear on a site-specific search, where people already know and trust the site, rather than in the main listings.

Comment: Then Google should offer "authorized review aggregator" programs for trusted shops or websites.